# JMeter - How to switch to different proxy settings while recording

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter and need help on issue with proxy server settings while clicking the link from that has different url. 
  Configured proxy settings in Firefox to  localhost and updated the port number. 
  When I record the web application using these settings it works.
  But there is a link within the web application that redirects to 2nd url which has different port number. This is where my recording script is failing.

The error I receive is "The proxy server is refusing connections"

```
 Is there any way to change the browser settings and continue to run the 2nd url successfully without any issues ?
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, add a firefox addon like 'proxyswitch' for switch proxy ports and break your recording into two steps.

You may try the following steps after you installed firefox addon,

1. Add two HTTP(S) Test script recorder in jmeter test scenario
2. Try setting one port for every proxy and start both the recorder
3. Switch the proxy to the first port and start recording till the second link
4. Now switch to the second port and follow the recording

HTH

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I tried but didnt work. Issue is when I click the link from the web application, that new link has different port number. However I will retry and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try telling your browser to use JMeter's proxy for all protocols

[image: Proxy for all protocols]

2. If option 1 does not resolve your issue you still should be able to record your test scenario via [Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which doesn't require proxy, certificates or any extra configuration, just follow your test scenario in Chrome and export recorded steps as JMeter .jmx file.

Answer (score 0):

In the JMeter application, verify that the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder port is the same as the proxy port configured in the browser settings.